# What is solution for "The file couldn’t be opened." UserInfo={NSURL=ftp:/xxxx:xxx@2011@ftp.xxx.com:21/}?

Tags: ios, swift, ftp, ftp-client

I am trying to call FTP server api and want to get file name when api is success. 
Below code I tried for call api,

```
let host = "ftp.xxx.com"
        let user = "xxx"
        let password = "xxx@2011"
        let port = "21"

       let url = URL(string: "ftp://"+user+":"+password+"@"+host+":"+port+"/")
        var data: Data? = nil
        do {
            if let anUrl = url {
                data = try Data(contentsOf: anUrl)
                print(data!)
            }
        } catch {
            print("Unexpected error: \(error).")
        }
```

When run this code I am getting error like

*Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=256 "The file couldn’t be opened." UserInfo={NSURL=ftp:/xxxx:xxx@2011@ftp.xxx.com:21/}.*

Please give me any solution to solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the plain `@` inside the password. This means `ftp://xxxx:xxx@2011@ftp.xxx.com:21/` gets interpreted as connecting to server `2011@ftp.xxx.com` with username `xxxx` and password `xxx`, which is obviously wrong.

The solution should be to URL-encode the special character `@` to `%40`, i.e. use the URL

```
ftp://xxx:xxx%402011@ftp.xxx.com:21/
```

Comment: Thank you so much... it works fine...
it prints 223 bytes.

Comment: @Vikas: Your original question is answered. Please don't ask new questions within a comment but ask a new question instead. Only this way you can make sure that other see it since nobody will be looking in the comment section for question.

Comment: I was having the same problem, also in my password also having @. I also replaced it by  %40.
But Unfortunately, not working for me, through same error

Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=256 "The file couldn’t be opened." UserInfo={NSURL=ftp://pintu.rajput:p!xxxxm%40r+32!@0.0.0.0:21/newfolder/image.png}

Comment: @PintuRajput: Interesting information. But to treat it as question please ask a new question instead of the comment and explicitly reference this one in your new question and add, what you've tried and that it does not solve your problem.